# Heroku working differently than running locally

Tags: javascript, heroku, nuxt.js

I created a Nuxt app with express backend, and i have registered some api routes. When i run locally as production `npm run build && npm run start` it works just fine.
[Here it is working locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UD0c.png)
However when i run it with heroku `heroku local web` all the API routes throw a 404.
[Here it doesn't work with heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JJYs.png)

Here is my server code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING);

const app = express();
// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready();
  }

  app.use('/api', require('./routes'));

  // session
  app.use(
    session({
      sessionDataHere
    })
  );

  // enable cors
  app.use(cors());

  // body parser
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(error.response);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host);

  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  });
}
start();
```

And here is the index of my routes

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const authRouter = require('./auth');
const videoRouter = require('./video');

const baseRouter = Router();

baseRouter.use('/', authRouter);
baseRouter.use('/', videoRouter);
baseRouter.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('This is working!'));

module.exports = baseRouter;
```

Maybe i'm missing something on the heroku configuration? Thanks!

Comment: What's your logs? $heroku logs -t

Comment: yes, sorry here it is:
`2020-02-12T22:42:24.074236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/test" host=hostHere request_id=requestId fwd="someIP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=404 bytes=42440 protocol=https`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i fixed it. I had to change my procfile. It was running `nuxt start` not `npm start` so it wasn't running any of the server side code